# How to install Archlinux on a acer emachines em350?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, installation, arch-linux, wifi-driver

Do a 64 bits version will work better if the cpu is 64 bits capable ?

Can I remove all added stuffs on Archbang or CTKArchLive to return to plain Archlinux with openbox that I can configure myself easily, so I can install Archlinux faster ?

I tried and installed Arch properly but I need to install the broadcom bcm 4727 driver (b43,wl,sta,open source), which driver do I need and how can I install it by my usb on Archlinux CLI made with base, sudo and wireless_tools only ?

Comment: why was this question voted down?

Comment: @kalaracey I think it was down-voted because it the multiple questions in the text do not expound upon the title question with specificity. Maybe try to edit the question so it does not roam too much. One question at a time, is the idea .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arch linux 64bit version is very stable and usable IF your cpu is 64 bit capable although you probably should enable the multilib repository (so you can install 32 bit packages).

You can either install arch linux from scratch or try trimming it back, however I have no experience with the distros you mentions so this is up to you. I would recommend just backing up all your data and starting from a clean install.

Create a bootable CD/USB and install. You can download any missing packages manually from packages.archlinux.org and put it onto another usb device to get it over. Then mount and install it

```
mount /dev/somewhere /mnt/somewhere
pacman -U /mnt/somewhere/my_awesome_package
```

However I beleive the b43 driver is part of the kernel now, try this (as root or use sudo)

```
modprobe b43
```

Answer (score 1):

This could sound a little late, since you may have found a solution on that.

I own the same machine and I am in the middle of installation of Archlinux. I choose i686 since the 64bits support on the Intel N450 seems to be partial and the CPU could be not able to cope with increased work by 64bits-only calls.

The wireless driver should be `wl`. It is possible to install that quite simply, but before that you need a working connection (best solution is probably ethernet, since it's automatically recognized and configured).

After base installation, you need to install yaourt following the instructions on [ArchLinux.fr site](http://archlinux.fr/yaourt-en).

Then you can simply call:

```
yaourt -S broadcom-wl
```

More details on [this page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Broadcom_wireless#broadcom-wl). A pair of minutes just to compile the modules and you are ready to go :)

Please be aware that I need to fix names of interfaces after adding the drivers to the MODULES array in /etc/rc.conf (it reverses ethernet with wireless, calling the wifi interface `eth0`).

Hope this will help.